# I just tried writting system() function using fork() and exec(). Is it a better method?

Tags: linux, c

```
#include<stdio.h>
#include<string.h>
#include<unistd.h>
#include<sys/types.h>
#include<sys/wait.h>
#include<error.h>
#define size 30
char *get_command(int argc, char *argv[]);
int my_system(const char *command);

int my_system(const char *command)
{
    int ret = 0;

    ret = execl("/bin/sh", "sh", "-c", command, (char *)NULL);
    if (ret == -1)
        error(1, 0, "error occcured in the execl() system call\n");
    return 0;
}

char *get_command(int argc, char **argv)
{
    int i = 0;
    static char command[size];

    strcpy(command, argv[1]);
    for (i = 2; i < argc; i++) {
        strcat(command, " ");
        strcat(command, argv[i]);
    }
    return command;
}

int main(int argc, char *argv[])
{
    pid_t pid;
    pid_t ret;
    int ret_system;
    int i = 0;
    int wstatus;
    char *command;

    if (argc < 2)
        error(1, 0, "Too few arguments\n");
    printf("The pid of the parent-process is :%d\n", getpid());
    pid = fork();
    if (pid == -1) {
        error(1, 0, "error in creating the sub-process\n");
    } else if (pid == 0) {
        printf("The pid of the child- process is :%d\n", getpid());
        command = get_command(argc, argv);
        ret_system = my_system(command);
    } else {
        ret = waitpid(-1, &wstatus, 0);
        printf("The pid of the child that has terminated is %d and the status of exit is %d\n", ret, wstatus);
    }
    return 0;
}
```

I am trying hard for the movement of fork() to my_system function and not using exec shell instead of exec command, but I am unable to do it, I am finding it difficult. could you please help. I am a beginner. Thanks a lot.

```
int my_system(const char *command)
{
    pid_t pid;
    int wstatus  = 0;
    int ret = 0;

    if (command == NULL)
        return 1;
    pid = fork();
    if (pid == -1)
        return -1;
    else if (pid == 0) {
        execle("/bin/sh", "sh", "-c",command, (char *)NULL);
    } else {
        ret = waitpid(-1, &wstatus, 0);
    }
    return wstatus;
}

char *get_command(int argc, char **argv)
{
    int i = 0;
    static char command[size];

    if (argc == 1)
        return NULL;

    strcpy(command, argv[1]);
    for (i = 2; i < argc; i++) {
        strcat(command, " ");
        strcat(command, argv[i]);
    }
    return command;
}

int main(int argc, char *argv[])
{
    int ret;
    char *command;

    command = get_command(argc, argv);
    ret = my_system(command);
    if (ret == 1)
        printf("Command is NULL, shell is available\n");
    else if (ret == -1)
        printf("Child process could not be created\n");
    else
        printf("The status is :%d\n", ret);
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: This is a C programming question, and belongs better on Stack Overflow.

Answer (score 2):

To make your system call, be like the built in one, you should move `fork` into it.

`get_command` has a bug. It returns a pointer to a stack variable. The behaviour of this is undefined (it may work for a bit, then stop).

No need to check return value of `exec`: If it returns then there is an error. Therefore the variable ret_system will only ever receive 0.

Also you don't need to us a shell (unless you were to use it: globing, variable expansion. You are not doing this).

## Is it better?

- `system` is portable (to MS-Windows, and other minor OSes).
- `fork` and `exec` is more powerful. E.g. allows for setting up of pipes.
- There are other high level libraries that give good abstractions for most uses.
- Using `fork` and `exec` is good for learning, even if you would be better off using high-level libraries (or abstract it yourself).

Comment: Could you please help me with the movement of fork() into my_system.  I am trying that for a very long time but i am unable to do it. Please .Thanks :)